# aggregate function in apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate, apache-spark-2.0

I need to aggregate a dataset based on a time interval for 1 min. When i try this, it throws error :

My dataset looks like this

```
scala> newVX.show
+--------------------+-----+
|            datetime|value|
+--------------------+-----+
|2017-07-31 10:53:...| 0.26|
|2017-07-31 10:53:...| 0.81|
|2017-07-31 09:45:...| 0.42|
|2017-07-31 09:44:...|0.008|
|2017-07-31 09:37:...| 0.14|
|2017-07-31 09:35:...|0.365|
|2017-07-31 09:34:...|0.485|
|2017-07-31 09:33:...| 0.49|
|2017-07-31 09:28:...| 1.15|
|2017-07-31 09:27:...|0.325|
|2017-07-31 09:24:...|0.845|
|2017-07-31 09:24:...|0.045|
|2017-07-31 09:23:...|0.015|
|2017-07-31 09:20:...| 0.45|
|2017-07-31 09:20:...| 0.05|
|2017-07-31 09:19:...| 0.14|
|2017-07-31 09:18:...| 0.24|
|2017-07-31 09:12:...|0.125|
|2017-07-31 09:11:...|  0.3|
|2017-07-31 09:11:...| 0.13|
+--------------------+-----+


scala> newVX.groupBy("datetime","60 seconds").agg(avg("value")).show
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "60
>   seconds"
>       among (datetime, value);
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(Dataset.scala:216)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(Dataset.scala:216)
>         at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.resolve(Dataset.scala:215)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$groupBy$2.apply(Dataset.scala:1442)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$groupBy$2.apply(Dataset.scala:1442)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala
>       :234)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala
>       :234)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:
>       59)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>         at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>         at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.groupBy(Dataset.scala:1442)
>         ... 58 elided

I also tried another solution . but It give values for every 60 rows instead of aggregating.

```
scala> newVX.groupBy(window($"datetime","1 minute")).agg(avg("value") as "avg-va
lue").show()


17/07/31 12:41:02 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 4456448 by
tes, TID = 5
+--------------------+-------------------+
|              window|          avg-value|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|[2017-07-31 07:49...| 0.7699999809265137|
|[2017-07-31 05:34...|0.33500000834465027|
|[2017-07-31 04:26...|0.23999999463558197|
|[2017-07-30 20:04...| 0.9399999976158142|
|[2017-07-29 08:33...|0.20250000059604645|
|[2017-07-28 09:30...| 0.3400000035762787|
|[2017-07-27 16:36...| 1.2799999713897705|
|[2017-07-27 08:16...| 0.3400000035762787|
|[2017-07-27 08:11...| 0.3400000035762787|
|[2017-07-27 01:06...| 0.4650000035762787|
|[2017-07-26 23:53...|0.23999999463558197|
|[2017-07-26 19:49...| 0.3199999928474426|
|[2017-07-25 14:39...| 0.3400000035762787|
|[2017-07-25 07:54...| 0.7099999785423279|
|[2017-07-25 06:21...|0.29499998688697815|
|[2017-07-25 03:57...| 0.1899999976158142|
|[2017-07-24 20:31...| 1.2799999713897705|
|[2017-07-24 19:50...| 1.2799999713897705|
|[2017-07-24 16:26...|0.03999999910593033|
|[2017-07-24 16:10...|              0.125|
+--------------------+-------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Edit: I made a few corrections here and it still showing wrong result. I retained date till minute value by giving

```
val VX = newvx.withColumn("datetime", ((unix_timestamp($"datetime") / 60)
.cast("long") * 60).cast("timestamp"))
```

after i aggregate it still shows the wrong value.

```
scala> VX.groupBy("datetime").agg(Map("value" -> "mean")).show
17/07/31 15:58:15 WARN Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 4456448 by
tes, TID = 21
+-------------------+-------------------+
|           datetime|         avg(value)|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2017-07-31 06:38:00| 0.6100000143051147|
|2017-07-30 19:46:00| 0.3400000035762787|
|2017-07-30 09:24:00|0.42500001192092896|
|2017-07-29 08:53:00| 0.8899999856948853|
|2017-07-29 15:07:00| 0.3400000035762787|
|2017-07-29 05:26:00| 0.3100000023841858|
|2017-07-28 23:29:00|0.27250000834465027|
|2017-07-28 22:07:00| 0.3199999928474426|
|2017-07-28 20:48:00| 0.2849999964237213|
|2017-07-28 20:13:00|0.44999998807907104|
|2017-07-28 18:07:00|0.20999999344348907|
|2017-07-28 06:38:00|0.08500000089406967|
|2017-07-27 11:27:00|0.26499998569488525|
|2017-07-27 02:37:00| 1.0549999475479126|
|2017-07-27 02:12:00| 0.3449999988079071|
|2017-07-26 22:22:00| 0.4699999988079071|
|2017-07-25 15:22:00| 0.8199999928474426|
|2017-07-25 07:08:00| 0.2800000011920929|
|2017-07-25 06:42:00|0.32499998807907104|
|2017-07-25 04:42:00|0.30000001192092896|
+-------------------+-------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Any idea why? and how do i correct it? Thank you.

Comment: How are the values not correct?

Comment: I have given the time as "1 min". But it is not giving " 1 min" value. As you can see from above, it gives random values from the table. It must start from 2017-07-31 10:53:..  but the output starts from 2017-07-31 06:38:00

Comment: Have you tried sorting before using show?

Comment: It's already sorted. I see that aggregation takes place  hours, instead of every minute

Comment: Try and reduce your data to a minimally reproducible example - Maybe just three dates and values, so it's more evident what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following approach:

create a user define function in spark that will retain only the date
   till minute grain level. Eg 2017-07-31 10:53

```
def atMinute = udf((dateTime: String) => // implement here retain date till minute)
```

transfrom initial dataframe using the udf

```
val df_at_minute = df.withColumn("datetime_at_min", atMinute("datetime"))
```

Apply the aggregate function to the new dataframe

```
 df_at_minute.groupBy("datetime_at_min").agg(avg("value"))
```

Comment: Hi, i retained the date till minute by doing like this : `val VX = newvx.withColumn("datetime", ((unix_timestamp($"datetime") / 60)
.cast("long") * 60).cast("timestamp"))`  and it worked perfectly fine . But when i `groupyBy` and use `avg`, it still giving random result.

Comment: I think it's a problem more related to how you compute the datetime field, cause the aggregation it;s ok